# Spark No space left on device on WordCount

Tags: apache-spark

I am facing issue of No disk space while doing a WordCount on Single Node standalone cluster with deploy-mode client.

File size is 50gb & My system has 30+ gb of Ram & 1000gb mounted disk.

```
at java.io.FileOutputStream.writeBytes(Native Method)
        at java.io.FileOutputStream.write(FileOutputStream.java:326)
        at org.apache.spark.storage.TimeTrackingOutputStream.write(TimeTrackingOutputStream.java:58)
        at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flushBuffer(BufferedOutputStream.java:82)
        at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flush(BufferedOutputStream.java:140)
        at net.jpountz.lz4.LZ4BlockOutputStream.flush(LZ4BlockOutputStream.java:240)
        at org.apache.spark.storage.DiskBlockObjectWriter.commitAndGet(DiskBlockObjectWriter.scala:172)
        at org.apache.spark.util.collection.ExternalSorter.writePartitionedFile(ExternalSorter.scala:701)
        at org.apache.spark.shuffle.sort.SortShuffleWriter.write(SortShuffleWriter.scala:72)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:96)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:53)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:109)
        at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:345)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)

    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Comment: What storage system you are using for spark?

Comment: its a linux file system which may be ext3 or ext4. But its not hdfs. & m reading this file from s3

Comment: the error is like Error writing stream to file inside spark  /work directory which further says that No space left on device.

Comment: Can you add your error logs here?

Comment: I have changed SPARK_LOCAL_DIRS path but still some how its using both /work and the path which I have given.

Comment: Job is failing at ShuffleMapStage

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was space for which I have changed below spark directories:

1. tmp directory
2. work directory
3. warehouse directory

initially it was using root which I have changed to the path to mounted disk.